# How do I get qmake to add -lm after -lpthread in the linking phase

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cuda, linker-flags

I am trying to compile a project on an armhf platform (Jetson board) that uses Qt and Cuda. It uses qmake to build.

It gets through the build phase to the end when it links, where it fails with the error below. Whatever I try to put in the project file, it does not add "-lm" after "-lpthread", in the Makefile that it generates. I think that would fix my problem here.

The error I get is:

```
undefined reference to symbol 'dlsym@@GLIBC_2.4'
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: I actually needed "-lm -ldl -lrt". It works when I manually add these to the end of the last g++ command line where it fails. Then it generates a binary that runs.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this to prepend the math library into the `LIBS` variable so that you ensure that it is the first thing for the linker:

```
LIBS = -lm $$LIBS
```

Comment: when I use QMAKE_LIBS+=-lm -ldl -lrt" it inserts "-lm -ldl -lrt" into the command line, but it still fails. It only works when I put those three libraries at the very end of the g++ command line. This I have needed to do manually.

Comment: I don't, really. It is an open source Cuda project, but I am building it on the Tegra Jetson board, which is an armhf architecture. (Project cuda-z in Sourceforge)

Comment: @AOSP_junkie: ok, well, it is hard to help without being able to reproduce the issue.